# How do I get a list of "subfolders" in a configuration file

Tags: java

I have a FileConfiguration config:

```
Homes:
  name:
    X: 10
    Y: 10
    Z: 10
  otherhome:
    X: 100
    Y: 100
    Z: 100
  spawn:
    X: 1000
    Y: 1000
    Z: 100
```

How do I get a List of the "subfolders" of the **Homes** "folder"?

Output:

```
name
otherhome
spawn
```

config.get something maybe?

Comment: You need to map your config file to a tree data structure. Then, you can get the sub folders of a node in the tree by listing all its children.

Comment: I mean the sub things of the Homes thing.